# Can Robots push when moving sideways?

Tags: robo-rally-2016

With "Boink" and "Crab Legs" robots can move sideways. Can they push other robots then when not facing them?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from [page 6 of the rules](https://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/roborally.pdf):

> **Pushing Other Robots**
>
> When robots collide, one will push the other. Robots can be pushed
>   anywhere on the board (or off the side!), even into a pit or onto a
>   conveyor belt. A robot can’t be pushed through a wall, though, so the
>   movement of a pushing robot will simply stop if the pushed robot runs
>   into a wall. Robots can run into walls all day long without taking any
>   damage from it, so they don’t accumulate Damage tokens this way.

You always push robots, unless a wall prevents them from moving. So there is no mention of direction. As long as they collide they are moved.

This also works recursively. If robot A pushes robot B and robot B collides with robot C, then robot C is moved too (as long as there is no wall preventing movement of either robot.

Comment: That is not the relevant rule book.. The 2016 wording is: If a robot enters a space occupied by another robot, the robot in motion will push the robot in the direction the pushing robot is moving until it ends is move.

Comment: That still leads to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Robots always push when moving into other robots.